# Dynamics 365 Marketing - In which table can I find Marketing Email Activities?

Tags: dynamics-crm

We're doing integration work and need access to Marketing Email Activities as they appear on Contact Timelines.

The Marketing Activity and Activity tables do not appear to contain any records for Marketing Email Activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marketing Email Activities are classed as Interaction data so you can't access a table directly to get them.

"Interaction data is stored in the marketing-insights service database and includes information about how your contacts interact with your marketing initiatives, including email opens, email clicks, event registrations, page submissions, and more."

You can't view interaction data directly, but you can export it to Azure blob storage. From there you can access the data. There is Microsoft documentation on how to do this.

[Connect Marketing Analytics to Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/marketing/custom-analytics#set-up-azure-blob-storage-and-connect-it-to-marketing)

Comment: Thanks. Microsoft Support confirmed the same. We're now attempting to retrieve the data via Azure Blob Storage REST API.